# PDF scaling error using ghostscript/PHP

Tags: php, ghostscript

I have been brought back on to a project that I worked on over a year ago in order to solve some issues.  The most pressing is that certain PDF documents fail to convert when thrown through the GS script I had created.  The vast majority of them work fine using the following:

(example) gs -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPDFFitPage -g600x775 -r300 -dAutoRotatePages=/All -sOutputFile=/home//converter_files/converted/111_done.pdf -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH /home/edited/converter_files/in/111.pdf

That creates a document most of the time that works fine in our iOS app that we are using the PDFs in.  However, the few documents that have unknown (as of now) origin will cause this error:

Warning: exec() [function.exec]: Unable to fork [gs -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPDFFitPage -g600x775 -r300 -dAutoRotatePages=/All -sOutputFile=/home/edited/converter_files/converted/111_done.pdf -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH /home/edited/converter_files/in/111.pdf] in /home/edited/public_html/2012test.php on line 41

I'm at a loss at this point.  Anyone have any ideas to try?  Not sure why those particular files won't convert.  I'm trying to get a version of PDF that has the issue but does not contain sensitive client info in it so I can get some more help, but as of now I can't share any of the PDFs with the issue due to sensitive client info.

Comment: Have you tried converting these files directly using Ghostscript ? Does this work ? If not then this is probably a Ghostscript error and can be reported as a bug. If it does work then your problem is some PHP issue, and I certainly know nothing about it...

Comment: I just did and it choked on the file still.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't even realize I could do that locally on my machine.  I can get other files to convert fine using the same switches, so I know it's the file itself with the issue.

Comment: OK so if Ghostscript itself doesn't like the file then it should have given you an error, what did it say ?